# Populating a form post parameter with all other input values aggregated into one

Tags: javascript, html, post

I am interfacing with an API which has an awkward method of taking data.

I have a form with Job Vacancy information submitted by a user: Firstname, lastname etc. etc.

The API only uses one POST parameter - 'params' - which is all the information entered onto the form, split into predefined fields using their own structure, eg:

```
params="Prop1:firstname;Prop2:lastname;Prop3:emailaddress"
```

Their application then decodes this at the other end

So my form current has a bunch of input field, eg

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
```

But I need to take all these values and aggregate them once the user has entered them, into one single parameter as above.

At the moment I am testing this with a textarea using hardcoded values in a single variable using php and it all submits OK.

```
<textarea name="params" rows="2" cols="150">'.$textsubmitvalue.'</textarea>
```

But is there a straightforward way to get the input values into the `$textsubmitvalue` variable?  (I could hide the text area).

Basically, I'm struggling to find the best approach to this - there's more than 40 fields - so any pointers appreciated.

*Edit - example of the whole form structure

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.example.com/rest/candidate/">

    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name (Required)" class="input-xlarge" required="">

    :
    :

    <textarea name="params" rows="2" cols="150">'.$textsubmitvalue.'</textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Application" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Comment: Do your form directly send data to 3rd-party API?

Comment: Yes - I've edited to add in a better overview of the form

Comment: Assuming your form directly interacts with 3rd-party site your question is related to `HTML`/`Javascript`, not `PHP`. You have to change tags

Comment: Done.  I think I was trying to avoid using javascript to do this, but I really have no idea of the best approach

Comment: I suggest to add 2nd form on the same page with hidden input and add listener to 'onsubmit' event on the 1st form which will aggregate data from the 1st form in the hidden input and trigger submitting 2nd form data.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a foreach loop on all the $_GET / $_POST vars to put them in one single string, something like this:

```
<?php 
$received;
foreach($_POST as $key=> $value){
   $received.= $key.'='.$value';';
}

// do something with received
echo $received;
```

?>

Comment: Thanks.  that won't work for me as I don't have access to the $_POST vars - they are all handled by the API